# How to specify that gem is JRuby platform only?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I am working on a gem which will only work for JRuby platform.

How can I specify that in my .gemspec?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply put in gemspec
    `spec.platform = 'java'` means it works with JRuby only.
to specifically set the platform you can take a look:
[Ruby gem Specification Reference](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#platform)